# Newton's Method in perl

Tags: perl, calculus, newtons-method

Okay so for my math class we were asked to write a program that performs and prints Newton's method until the values converge and we have a root for the function. At first I thought it would be easy. It was until I just couldn't get the values derived from the first time to be used the second time. My knowledge of the language is basic. Really basic, so what you're about to see might not be pretty.

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use PDL;

print "First guess? (this is x0)\n";
$xorig = <>;

do {
  &fx;
} until ($fex == 0);

sub fx {

  if ($xn == 0) {
    $x = $xorig;
  }
  else {
    $x = $xn;
  }

  print "What is the coefficient (for each factor) of your function?\n";
  $fcx = <STDIN>;
  push @coefficient_of_x, $fcx;

  print "... times x to the (enter exponent, if no exponent, enter 1. if no x, enter 0)?\n";
  $fex = <STDIN>;
  push @exponent_x, $fex;

  chomp ($fcx, $fex, $x, $xorig);

  $factor = $fcx * ($x ** $fex);
  push @fx, $factor;
}

my $fx = 0;
foreach my $variable (@fx) {
  $fx = $variable + $fx #THIS PROVIDES A VALUE FOR THE GIVEN F(X) WITH A GIVEN X VALUE
}
print "f($x)=$fx\n";

do {
  &fprimex;
} until ($fprimeex == 0);

sub fprimex {

  if ($xn == 0) {
    $x = $xorig;
  }
  else {
    $x = $xn;
  }

  print "What is the coefficient (for each factor) of your derivative function?\n";
  $fprimecx = <STDIN>;
  push @coefficient_of_fpx, $fprimecx; 

  print "... times x to the (enter exponent, if no exponent, enter 1. if no x, enter 0)?\n";
  $fprimeex = <STDIN>;
  push @exponent_fpx, $fprimeex;

  chomp ($fprimecx, $fprimeex, $x, $xorig);

  $factorprime = $fprimecx * ($x ** $fprimeex);
  push @fprimex, $factorprime;
}

$fprimex = 0;
foreach my $variableprime (@fprimex) {
  $fprimex = $variableprime + $fprimex #THIS PROVIDES A VALUE FOR THE GIVEN F'(X) WITH THAT SAME X VALUE
}
print "f'($x)=$fprimex\n";

sub x0 {
  $xn = $xorig - $fx / $fprimex; #THIS IS NEWTON'S METHOD EQUATION FOR THE FIRST TIME
  push @newxn, $xn;
  print "xn ia $xn\n";
}

&x0;

foreach $value (@exponent_x) {
  $exponent_x = $xn ** $value;
  push @part1, $exponent_x;
  $part1 = @part1;
}

foreach $value2 (@coefficient_of_x) {
  $part2 = $value2 * @part1;
  push @final1, $part2;
}

print "@part1\n";
print "@final1\n";
```

Essentially what it is is I first ask for the first guess. I use this value to define the coefficients and the exponents of f(x) to get a value for f(x) in terms of the given x. I do it again for f'(x). Then I perform newton's method the first time and get the new value xn. But I'm having a hard time to get values for f(xn) and f'(xn), meaning I can't get x(n+1) and can't continue newton's method. I need help.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Perl.

I would strongly recommend the following changes to your code:

1. Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY Perl script.
2. Always [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your input from STDIN as your taking it:

   ```
   chomp( my $input = <STDIN> );
   ```
3. Don't needlessly create subroutines, especially for one-off scripts such as this.
4. Instead of using the [statement modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) form of [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html), I would recommend using an infinite [`while`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/while.html) with loop control statements to exit:

   ```
   while (1) {

       last if COND;
   }
   ```
5. Finally, since the coefficients of your polynomial are all associated with an exponent for X, I would recommend using a %hash for conveniently saving those values.

As demonstrated:

```
#!usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Build your Polynomial:\n";

my %coefficients;

# Request each Coefficient and Exponent of the Polynomial
while (1) {
    print "What is the coefficient (for each factor) of your function? (use a bare return when done)\n";
    chomp( my $coef = <STDIN> );

    last if $coef eq '';

    print "... times x to the (enter exponent, if no exponent, enter 1. if no x, enter 0)?\n";
    chomp( my $exp = <STDIN> );

    $coefficients{$exp} = $coef;
}

print "\nFirst guess? (this is x0)\n";
chomp( my $x = <> );

# Newton's Method Iteration
while (1) {
    my $fx  = 0;
    my $fpx = 0;

    while ( my ( $exp, $coef ) = each %coefficients ) {
        $fx += $coef * $x**$exp;
        $fpx += $coef * $exp * $x**( $exp - 1 ) if $exp != 0;
    }

    print "   f(x) = $fx\n";
    print "   f'(x) = $fpx\n";

    die "Slope of 0 found at $x\n" if $fpx == 0;

    my $new_x = $x - $fx / $fpx;

    print "Newton's Method gives new value for x at $new_x\n";

    if ( abs($x - $new_x) < .0001 ) {
        print "Accuracy reached\n";
        last;
    }

    $x = $new_x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. A lot. This makes a lot more sense than what I was doing before. Asking the user for input twice is really annoying, and I was getting annoyed just testing it over and over. Your suggestions are very helpful, and they'll help me out as I try to learn more. As you can probably tell, my knowledge and experience are minimal. I just realized that there is one more problem. One of the problems I have to use this for involve trig functions. Is there an easy way that I could work that into this?

Answer (score 3):

I am having trouble working out what you intended with your code. The main problem seems to be that don't have it clear in your head what each of your subroutines do, as `fx` and `fprimex` ask for the data as well as evaluating the function (except for summing the terms which, oddly, is done outside the subroutine). That isn't what you want at all, as the exponents and coefficients remain constant throughout a program that has to evaluate those functions many times, and you really don't want to ask for the values again each time.

Here are some pointers to getting Perl code working in general

- Write your program in tiny chunks -- a line or two at a time -- and check after each addition that the program compiles and runs and produces the expected results. Writing an entire program before you even try to run it is a recipe for disaster
- *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings`, and declare every variable with `my` as close as possible to the point where it is first used. You have many undeclared variables which are therefore global, and passing information between sections of code using global variables is a good way to lose yourself in your own code. It is a good rule for a subroutine to use *only* parameters passed to it or variables declared within it
- `chomp` variables as soon as they are read, either from a file or from the terminal. A useful idiom to trim input strings at source is

  ```
  chomp(my $input = <>)
  ```

  which will ensure that there are no stray newlines anywhere in your data

That at least should get you started.

I'm in two minds about showing this. I hope it will help you, but I really don't want to drag you into parts of Perl that you're not familiar with.

It's a program that uses the *Newton–Raphson* method to find the root of polynomials. I've skipped the terminal input for now, and hard-coded the data. As it stands it finds the square root of 3,000 by finding the positive root of *x<sup>2</sup> - 3000*.

Note that `@f` and `@f_prime` hold the *coefficients* of the function and its derivative *backwards* from the usual order, so `@f` is `(-3000, 0, 1)`. The program also calculates the coefficients of the derivative function, as it is a simple thing to do and far preferable to asking the user for another set of values.

There is just *one* subroutine `polynomial`, which takes a value for *x* and a list of coefficients. This is used to calculate the value of both the function and its derivative for a given value of *x*.

The algorithm step is in the line

```
my $new_x = $x - polynomial($x, @f) / polynomial($x, @f_prime);
```

which calculates *x - f(x) / f'(x)* and assigns it to `$new_x`. Each successive estimate is printed to STDOUT until the loop exits.

Comparing floating-point values for equality is a bad idea. The precision of computer floating-point values is, obviously, limited, and a sequence will probably never converge to the point where the last two values of the sequence are equal. The best that can be done is to check whether the absolute value of the difference between the last two values is below a reasonable delta. An accuracy of 10E12 is reasonable for 32-bit floating-point numbers. I have found that the series converges to within 10E14 quite reliably, but if you find that your program hangs in an endless loop then you should increase the margin.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @f       = reverse (1, 0, -3000);
my @f_prime = map { $f[$_] * $_ } 1 .. $#f;

my $x = 0.5;
print $x, "\n";

while () {
  my $new_x = $x - polynomial($x, @f) / polynomial($x, @f_prime);
  last if abs($new_x - $x) < $x / 1e14;
  $x = $new_x;
  print $x, "\n";
}

sub polynomial {
  my ($x, @coeffs) = @_;

  my $total = 0;
  my $x_pow = 1;

  for my $coeff (@coeffs) {
    $total += $x_pow * $coeff;
    $x_pow *= $x;
  }

  $total;
}
```

**output**

```
0.5
3000.25
1500.62495833681
751.312062703027
377.652538627869
192.798174296885
104.179243809523
66.4878834504349
55.8044433107163
54.7818016853582
54.7722565822241
54.7722557505166
```

Comment: This is really great too. The only thing I'm not sure I would be able to do is work the user input into it easily, and without asking for a ton of information. At one point I was so lost that I was just making subroutines that I could call on if I had another idea that I thought could help.

Comment: @Lucas: Handling user input should be fairly simple. Taking my code as an example, it's just a matter of writing some code that allows manual input of the values in `@f`, instead of assigning a literal list. You may or may not want to keep the line that differentiates the coefficients. After that, IMO it's best to write subroutines only if there is a large section of your algorithm that can be parcelled off as `do this`, or if there are multiple occurrences of *similar* processes that can be parameterised. I guess it takes experience, as well as a choice of style, to do that easily.

Comment: @Lucas: Maybe you should write the whole thing without subroutines? That would be a perfectly acceptable solution, and I'm sure you will notice if you tire of repeating the same code! Don't believe your tutor that *everything* should be in a subroutine, or that you should comment your code heavily. A good program should express its meaning through good choices of identifiers and judicious use of white space that separates the functionality into chunks. Only occasionally will you have to add minimal comments that explain why some line of code is necessary.

Comment: So in your code, if I asked user input and used `push` to push those variables into `@f` I could theoretically use the user given inputs? I just tried that and it didn't work, and I think I can attribute that to my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @Lucas: User input (and output) are by far the most awkward parts of programming. The intermediate manipulation of the data is trivial in comparison. There are many ways to do this. Forgetting about the coefficients for the derivative for now, all you want is a series of (for a quadratic) three numbers from the keyboard. You could accept all three numbers on one line, or one number per line. You must ask yourself what *you* would like to type to provide the input. Do you want to type, say, `1 0 -3000`? That would be by far the most simple. Or do you want to handle nonsense like `1 xx PI()`

Comment: @Lucas: If all you want is to get the data into the program, forgetting all niceties, then you can write just `my @f = reverse split ' ', <>`. Then, if you run your program and type `1 0 -3000`, the array `@f` will be just as it is with the literal assignment in my solution. You will want to add a prompt etc. but I hope you get the idea?

Comment: I tried. But when I typed in the values, it just ran infinitely and wouldn't stop. Here is what I entered `my @f = reverse split ' ', <>;
my @f_prime = map { $f[$_] * $_ } 1 .. $#f;

chomp (my $x = <>);
print $x, "\n";`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm being such a hassle. This is probably like dealing with a 3 year-old.

Comment: You don't need the second `<>`. The first line reads *all* the values into  `@f`. Remember what I said about testing in tiny chunks? Create a program that has *just* `my @f = reverse split ' ', <>` and `print "@f\n"`. Then you can see what that line is doing and splice it back into your main program.

Comment: Do you know how to use `Data::Dumper`? It's worth more than any number of my words in helping you fix your code. [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump) is far better again, but it isn't a core module and you may need to install it.